# Get the total distance from point to the end of linestring

Tags: python, distance, xy

I have a list of GPS coordinates that make up a bus route:

```
busRoute = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ... (xn, yn)]
```

I also have a point that may not be exactly on that route (due to GPS error):

```
currentLocation = (x, y)
```

Using Python, how can I get the total distance from the bus's `currentLocation` to the end of the `busRoute`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the [linear referencing methods](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linear-referencing-methods) with [Shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/).

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

# Example data
busRoute = LineString([(80, 380), (160, 380), (220, 370), (280, 330), (310, 210), (379, 185)])
currentLocation = Point(280, 350)

# The current location is not exactly on the bus route
print(busRoute.distance(currentLocation))  # 16.6410058868

# Distance along line to nearest projected point, from start
print(busRoute.project(currentLocation))  # 201.8446468877574

# .. and distance from end .. I think this is ultimately what you are looking for
print(busRoute.length - busRoute.project(currentLocation))  # 208.17654522066948

# and the point that is used, which is on the busRoute
print(busRoute.interpolate(busRoute.project(currentLocation)).wkt)
# POINT (270.7692307692307700 336.1538461538461900)
```