# Routing from somewhere along an edge in osmnx

Tags: python, shapely, osmnx

I have an `osmnx` network in Python that has long edges, and points along those edges that I'd like to route to and from. Routing based on the nearest node is a non-starter because the edges are long. Is there a way to route from/to somewhere along an edge in `osmnx`?

I'm aware of finding the nearest edge to a point using `ox.distance.get_nearest_edge`, and I know how to perform linear referencing using Shapely methods. But neither of those quite gets me where I need to go.

Comment: Does [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59178/get-the-total-distance-from-point-to-the-end-of-linestring) help?